# Amazon Deepracer: Sensors and Parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm having a difficult time understanding sensors and parameters in Deepracer. It talks about adding optional sensors (like cameras and LIDAR) - and OTOH there are all sorts of parameters I can use (compass heading, wheel angle, distance from centerline, etc).

I just doing model training - is there a correlation to sensors vs parameters? Like - I can only get distance-to-objects if I have LIDAR, or track-width if I have camera, etc?

If not - why would I even want any of these sensors? How would they be used? How would it get this other data without these sensors?

Or is it case where a car always HAS access to all of these parameters, regardless of the sensors equipped (I don't know how that would work) - but adding sensors just make it more accurate - only with a real-world car??

Answer (score 0):

The LIDAR sensors were added this year, you'll want these if you want to train a model for object detection.

The parameters (known as hyperparamaters) are configuration that you'd tune to improvde your model. If you're new to ML or Reinforcement Learning i'd suggest leaving them ass the default at first and instead focus on the reward function.

Comment: Not "hyperparameters" - the conventional parameters passed to the reward function

Comment: Ah right, the parameters will still be there regardless of sensors. But without LIDAR your model will struggle with object detection